# ionic title in header centerd despite text-align:left

Tags: html, css

I added a div with 6 buttons to my header, which are diplayed on my right, and now my title is no longer on the left. It is also not completely centerd.

```
<ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-header-bar style=" background-color:rgb(28,74,122)">
    <h1 class="title " style=" text-align:left; color:white;">Medexter Demo KIS</h1> 
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-clear button-light"><i class="icon ion-navicon"></i></button>

    <div class="BTNright">
      <button class="button button-clear button-light " ><p class="smallFont headIconText"><i class="icon ion-printer headIcon"></i>Print</p></button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light"><p class="smallFont headIconText"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back headIcon"></i>Back</p></button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light  "><p class="smallFont headIconText"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-forward headIcon"></i>Redo</p></button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light "><p class="smallFont headIconText"><i class="icon ion-search  headIcon"></i>Search</p></button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light"><p class="smallFont headIconText"><i class="icon ion-information headIcon"></i>Help</p></button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light"><p class="smallFont headIconText"><i class="icon ion-power headIcon"></i>Log Out</p></button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-side-menu-content>
```

When I leave out `text-align:left` then It is back in the center.

This is how my header currently looks like. [image: header]

As you can see the title is neighter on the lerft nor in the center.

Comment: The `<h1>` is `inline-block` in this case. You need to understand that each element is `float`ed `left` and you need to set `position`ing to overcome the issue.

Comment: It would be most helpful if you can create a snippet with [mcve].